how to design/build model to predict multi-dimension sequence data in python?
I have student test scores (grouped by student)
student_id   weekday   hour   age    location_id   score
──────────   ───────   ────   ───-   ───────────   ─────
alice           5       14    12.3       123         88   
alice           3        8    12.5       123         85
alice           3       11    12.8       555         92   
alice           1       10    13.1       888         90   
alice           2       16    13.3       123         82   
...
bob             1       10    13.1       555         97   
bob             3        8    13.3       888         90
bob             2        9    13.5       123         99   
bob             5       14    13.7       888         82     
bob             1       15    13.9       888         88    
...

and I would like to build a model that predicts a students "next" test score.
               ┌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┐
    student_id ╎ weekday   hour   age    location_id   score  ╎
    ────────── ╎ ───────   ────   ───-   ───────────   ─────  ╎◀╌╌ one input data point
    bob        ╎    1       10    13.1       555         97   ╎
               ╎                                              ╎
    bob        ╎    3        8    13.3       888         90   ╎
               ╎                                              ╎
    bob        ╎    2        9    13.5       123         99   ╎   
               ╎                                              ╎
    bob        ╎    5       14    13.7       888         82   ╎
               ╎                                      ┏━━━━━━━┪
    bob        ╎    1       15    13.9       888      ┃  88   ┃◀━━ output from predictor
               └╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┺━━━━━━━┛
                                                        

Each data point would contain data from only one student.
The number of rows can be fixed, if necessary... meaning, each data point would contain exactly n rows (n==5 in this example).
Oh also, each student would have MANY (rolling) data points.
Where can I find an example of a similarly architected model?
Can someone point me in the right general direction?
Please help me!!!
Thank you!!!

Welcome to Cross Validated! You've tagged this with [tag:tensorflow], which makes it appear that you already see this as a problem to be solved by deep learning. Could you please expand on that?

Hi @Dave! so I have been searching online & found some references to tensorflow and LSTM models, which I have tried... but I'm unable to figure out how to format the data to have this missing output... thank you for your response!

meaning, the only thing I can think of is to flatten the data... but that doesnt seem right

also ive been looking for weather prediction models... i assume it might be similar? cuz they have like day and humidity, etc... and then yesterdays temperature... i dont know... im frustrated

So is your question about how to code a software implementation?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Since you are having multiple observations (in time) per object (student) you are looking at something which in statistical analysis is called a panel data time-series. Popular models for this type of analysis are Linear Mixed Models. In Python, this is implemented in statsmodels, however there is a more custom implementation also in tensorflow.

this is exactly the answer i was looking for @deblue!!! THANK YOU!!!
